# Increases is a must or mustn't

Tags: salary

I would like to know, is a annual increase a must or are companies allowed to keep you on the same rates? 
I have approached my boss on more than one occasion and always get the "I am working on it - not now" Attitude/answer. 
I just want to know if what I am asking is not a must?

Comment: Depends on your specific contract with the employer so off topic,  voting to close

Comment: Unless your specific contract states that you are guaranteed a raise, a raise isn't guaranteed.

Comment: One company I worked for gave no raises for 4 years. To anyone.  And they had over a thousand employees.

Comment: @HLGEM if that's anything like my current company, payrises were not given because the group wasn't making enough profits... but the board of directors got huge bonuses for their "super hard work".

Answer (score 2):

This usually depends entirely on your contract so you should read that and make sure the company you're working for hasn't breached it. If there's nothing in there about a salary increase you're not owed anything extra.

It's quite common for a salary review to follow a performance review, and these tend to be annual. This would lead to the mindset that to get a pay rise you have to earn it, rather than automatically deserve it.

Comment: +1 some companies don't give raises, even when staff are promoted (like my workplace...)